# Why is FindBugs ignoring my check for null?

Tags: java, eclipse, findbugs

Can anyone explain me why this throws a findbug warning:

```
if (m != null && m.getModifiedDate() != null)
    content.put("ModifiedDate", m.getModifiedDate().getTime());
```

and this is working:

```
if(m != null){
    Date date = m.getModifiedDate();
    if (date  != null)
        content.put("ModifiedDate", date .getTime());
}
```

Warning: Possible null pointer dereference due to return value of called method.

Is there a possibilty to tell FindBugs that Example number 1 should not be a warning?

Comment: sorry forgot to paste it.. edited

Comment: running with -effort:max/effort=max might help, this will make findbugs work harder, which sometimes reduces error and corrects mistakes

Comment: @oers just tried it with no success.. I think i will have to refactor my code =(

Comment: @soulcinder can I ask which findbugs version you are using? I have to look into my reports, but I use this code quite often and never stumbled upon this error (or never noticed it? :))

Comment: @oers findbugs version: 2.0.0.20111221, did you annotate your getters with @CheckForNull?

Comment: no I didn't, and I still use 1.39 (probably behaves differently)

Comment: could it be this bug: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3484713&group_id=96405&atid=614693? Anyway it seems to be a false positive to me. I'd suggest asking on the mailing list to get a definite answer. The other answer here seems like a wild guess.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Possibly because `m.getModifiedDate()` could return a non-null value on the first call, but a null value on the second?

Comment: oh Ok! so is there a method to tell Findbugs that the sorrounding if check is enough?

Comment: Can you tell how returning null or non-null cause a warning in first case and not in 2nd case.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar: In the second case we're only calling `getModifiedDate()` once - the value of `date` isn't going to change to be null after the nullity check...

Comment: @soulcinder: Not that I'm aware of, but I don't know much about FindBugs.