# How to avoid deferencing NPE on return value when throwing an exception?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, sonarqube

I'm currently having an issue with SonarQube. I have a validator service ( that checks if the DTO I receive via API does not contain null values in Double and String object (not primitive).

When I use the validator service in the method below that fetches the data, Sonar is mentioning that there is a possible NullPointerException deference, and to be honest I have no idea how to overcome it. I've tried to invoke the method in a try catch block, but it still is higlighted in Sonar.

Edit: the exact message from sonar is Possible null pointer dereference in sendEmployeeRequest(EmployeeRequestDTO, HttpHeaders) due to return value of called method.

```
        validateNotNull(employeeResponseDTO.getGetSalary(), "Salary");
        validateNotNull(employeeResponseDTO.getBonus(), "Bonus");
        validateNotNull(employeeResponseDTO.getAge, "Age");

    }

    private void validateNotNull(final Object o, final String fieldName) {
        if (o == null) {
            throw new HRServiceException(MessageFactory.getExceptionByMessage(ERROR_TYPE, fieldName));
        }
    }
}
```

```
    public EmployeeResponseDTO sendEmployeeRequest(EmployeeRequestDTO employeeRequestDTO, HttpHeaders headers) {
        HttpEntity<EmployeeRequestDTO> entity = new HttpEntity<>(employeeDTO, prepareHeaders(requestHeaders));
        ResponseEntity<EmployeeRequestDTO> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(employeeServiceURL, entity, EmployeeResponseDTO.class);
        EmployeeResponseDTO employeeResponseDTO = new EmployeeResponseDTO();
        if (response.hasBody() && response.getBody() != null) {
            employeeResponseDTO = response.getBody();
            logger.info(SystemMessages.RESPONSE_RECEIVED);
            employeeValidator.validateEmployee(employeeResponseDTO);
        }
        return employeeResponseDTO;
    }
```

Edit: @Willem solution worked, below code for reference, and the thread found by @Willem. [Why is FindBugs ignoring my check for null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836208/why-is-findbugs-ignoring-my-check-for-null)

```
    public EmployeeResponseDTO sendEmployeeRequest(EmployeeRequestDTO employeeRequestDTO, HttpHeaders headers) {
        HttpEntity<EmployeeRequestDTO> entity = new HttpEntity<>(employeeDTO, prepareHeaders(requestHeaders));
        ResponseEntity<EmployeeRequestDTO> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(employeeServiceURL, entity, EmployeeResponseDTO.class);
        EmployeeResponseDTO employeeResponseDTO = response.getBody(); 
        if (employeeResponseDTO != null) {
            logger.info(SystemMessages.RESPONSE_RECEIVED);
            employeeValidator.validateEmployee(employeeResponseDTO);
        }
        return employeeResponseDTO;
    }
```

Comment: On what line is sonar mentioning that there is a possible NullPointerException deference?

Comment: `employeeValidator.validateEmployee(employeeResponseDTO);` is the line causing issues.

Comment: Looks like `employeeValidator` could be null. Where does `employeeValidator` come from?

Comment: where and how do you initialize employeeValidator ?

Comment: employeeValidator is a autowired Spring Bean initilized in the constructor of the service sending employee request.

Comment: can you make the variable final and check again?

Comment: According to sonar (https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3306) @momo solution should work

Comment: @momo do you mean the employeeResponseDTO? Making it final upon initialization will make me impossible to assign the response body to it, initializing it in the if clause will make it out of the scope for the return statement. Sorry if I'm misunderstood you.

Comment: @andrei_shev no he means your autowired `employeeValidator`

Comment: A `final` object can still be used via its methods (setters, etc). It just cannot be instantiated twice.

Comment: @Willem exactly. I just think that sonar may has troubles identifying that this variable will not be reinitialized ever.

Comment: I've made the field final, and passing now the final dependency in the constructor. I'm sorry if I confused you, the exact message from sonar is **Possible null pointer dereference in sendEmployeeRequest(EmployeeRequestDTO, HttpHeaders) due to return value of called method**. I will edit my post. It's after making it final.

Comment: @andrei_shev what about  if (response != null && response.hasBody()) { ... ?

Comment: @momo IDE is higlighting it as always true with reason "Method postForEntity() inherits annotation from pacakge org.springframework.web.client thus non-null"

Comment: @andrei_shev Just for curiosity, is Sonar still showing a potential NPE even if you add if (response != null ..) ?

Comment: Could it be that sonar is thinking `response.getBody()` will return different each call? like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836208/why-is-findbugs-ignoring-my-check-for-null might be worth a try to put the `response.getBody()` in a variable before the `if` and check null in the `if` on the variable instead of the method call.

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
if (response.hasBody() && response.getBody() != null) {
    employeeResponseDTO = response.getBody();
    logger.info(SystemMessages.RESPONSE_RECEIVED);
    employeeValidator.validateEmployee(employeeResponseDTO);
}
```

To:

```
if (response.hasBody() && response.getBody() != null) {
    employeeResponseDTO = response.getBody();
    logger.info(SystemMessages.RESPONSE_RECEIVED);
    if(employeeValidator == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    employeeValidator.validateEmployee(employeeResponseDTO);
}
```

Comment: this seems just to be a bad workaround. If you really want to go into this direction, then you should better throw an exception if employeeValidator is null or assert that it is not null.

Comment: This doesn't make sense either. Now your null check throws a NPE, that is exactly the same as if you would remove the if statement. Then a NPE would be thrown one line later.. So your if statement doesn't change the actual code at all.

Comment: It's not exactly the same. This is to tell the compiler that you know your object will not be null. The goal is to avoid the warning which is superfluous.

Comment: The question pertains to the compiler warning, not to the potential NPE.

Comment: The warning is from Sonar. The compiler won't check for NPE's

Comment: Possible de-referencing null pointer is a generic Java compiler warning. Granted this question pertains to Sonar, where in the question does it make it clear that the warning is explicitly from Sonar and not from the Java compiler? I approached this question as if it pertained to a Java application. Knowing nothing about Sonar, this would fix the compiler warning which is what the question asked. It's also a perfectly reasonable solution because you either 1) heed the warning or 2) tell the compiler you are confident there's not going to be a NPE. The question seems to prefer the latter.

Comment: @Willem the compiler will check for anti-patterns that make NPEs likely. But silencing the warning is also, sometimes, a legitimate strategy.

Comment: To silence the warning by pre-empting the NPE with a NPE is to tell the compiler "I'm confident this won't be null. Don't warn me. If it is null, then I'm ok with the NPE. I'll prove it by explicitly throwing one myself."